# Why fcntl() range lock (some offset to length) is slower as compared to fcntl full file lock (0 offset to EOF)?

Tags: files, filesystems, linux-kernel, ext4, system-calls

I am trying to write on 1 GB file from 8 different processes (every process will start writing from 0th offset till EOF) simultaneously; while following two different approaches.

1. Before writing every process will acquire whole file lock (0th offset - EOF) using fcntl(), even if they are writing in different regions of file.
2. Before writing every process will acquire lock using fcntl() only to respective region of file.

As per my understanding 2nd approach should take less time compared to 1st. But in my testing I have found 1st approach is taking less time. Can someone please explain why ?

Underlying FS : ext4

**First Apprach**

```
#define MAX_WRITE 65536

void write_file (char *path) {
        int fd;
        char buf[MAX_WRITE];
        ssize_t bytes_write;
        off64_t file_end, off;
        struct flock rl;

        fd = open64(path, O_WRONLY);
        if (fd == -1) {
                perror("open fail");
        }
        srand(time(0));
        char ch = (rand() % (33 - 122 + 1)) + 33;
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < MAX_WRITE - 3; i += 4) {
                buf[i] = ch;
                buf[i+1] = ch;
                buf[i+2] = ch;
                buf[i+3] = ch;
        }
        buf[i+3] = '\n';
        file_end = lseek64(fd, 0, SEEK_END);
        lseek64(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
        rl.l_type = F_WRLCK;
        rl.l_whence = SEEK_SET;
        rl.l_start = 0;
        rl.l_len = file_end;
        rl.l_pid = 0;
        for (off = 0; off < file_end; off+=bytes_write) {
                if (fcntl(fd, F_SETLKW, &rl) == -1) {
                        perror("fcntl locking failed");
                        exit(-1);
                }

                bytes_write = write(fd, buf, MAX_WRITE);
                if (bytes_write == -1) {
                        perror("Error writing file");
                        exit(-1);
                } else if (bytes_write < MAX_WRITE) {
                        printf("Partial write, only %ld no. of bytes are returned.\n",
                        bytes_write);
                }

                rl.l_type = F_UNLCK;
                if (fcntl(fd, F_SETLK, &rl) == -1) {
                        perror("fcntl locking failed");
                        exit(-1);
                }
        }
        printf("process %d Able to write %lld bytes..\n", getpid(), off);
        close(fd);
        return; 
}
int main (int argc, char **argv) {

        int fd, p_dead;
        if (argc < 3) {
                printf("Usage: %s <filename> <processes>\n", argv[0]);
                exit(-1);
        }
        char *path = argv[1];
        int p_no = atoi(argv[2]);

        /* Creating n number of processes */
        for (int i = 0; i < p_no; i++) {
                switch (fork()) {
                        case -1:
                                perror("fork failed:");
                                break;
                        case 0:
                                write_file(path);
                                exit(0);
                                break;
                        default:
                                /* Do nothing */
                                break;
                }
        }
        p_dead = 0;
        while (1) {
                if (wait(NULL) == -1) {
                        if (errno == ECHILD) {
                                printf("No child left..\n");
                                printf("Total no. of processes died : %d\n", p_dead);
                                exit(0);
                        } else {
                                perror("wait failed");
                                exit(-1);
                        }
                }
                p_dead++;
        }
        exit(0);
}
```

**Second Approach**

```
    #define MAX_WRITE 65536

void write_file (char *path) {
        int fd;
        char buf[MAX_WRITE];
        ssize_t bytes_write;
        off64_t file_end, off;
        struct flock rl;

        fd = open64(path, O_WRONLY);
        if (fd == -1) {
                perror("open fail");
        }
        srand(time(0));
        char ch = (rand() % (33 - 122 + 1)) + 33;
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < MAX_WRITE - 3; i += 4) {
                buf[i] = ch;
                buf[i+1] = ch;
                buf[i+2] = ch;
                buf[i+3] = ch;
        }
        buf[i+3] = '\n';
        file_end = lseek64(fd, 0, SEEK_END);
        lseek64(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
        rl.l_type = F_WRLCK;
        rl.l_whence = SEEK_CUR;
        rl.l_start = 0;
        rl.l_len = MAX_WRITE;
        rl.l_pid = 0;
        for (off = 0; off < file_end; off+=bytes_write) {
                if (fcntl(fd, F_SETLKW, &rl) == -1) {
                        perror("fcntl locking failed");
                        exit(-1);
                }
                bytes_write = write(fd, buf, MAX_WRITE);
                if (bytes_write == -1) {
                        perror("Error writing file");
                        exit(-1);
                } else if (bytes_write < MAX_WRITE) {
                        printf("Partial write, only %ld no. of bytes are returned.\n",
                        bytes_write);
                }
                rl.l_type = F_UNLCK;
                if (fcntl(fd, F_SETLK, &rl) == -1) {
                        perror("fcntl locking failed");
                        exit(-1);
                }
        }
        printf("process %d Able to write %lld bytes..\n", getpid(), off);
        close(fd);
        return;
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

        int fd, p_dead;
        if (argc < 3) {
                printf("Usage: %s <filename> <processes>\n", argv[0]);
                exit(-1);
        }
        char *path = argv[1];
        int p_no = atoi(argv[2]);

        /* Creating n number of processes */
        for (int i = 0; i < p_no; i++) {
                switch (fork()) {
                        case -1:
                                perror("fork failed:");
                                break;
                        case 0:
                                write_file(path);
                                exit(0);
                                break;
                        default:
                                /* Do nothing */
                                break;
                }
        }
        p_dead = 0;
        while (1) {
                if (wait(NULL) == -1) {
                        if (errno == ECHILD) {
                                printf("No child left..\n");
                                printf("Total no. of processes died : %d\n", p_dead);
                                exit(0);
                        } else {
                                perror("wait failed");
                                exit(-1);
                        }
                }
                p_dead++;
        }
        exit(0);
}
```

Comment: One thing is you're reusing `rl` to do the unlock, and you're not resetting `l_type` in the loop, so both of your examples are only locking on the first loop iteration.

Comment: @AndyDalton It solved the problem, Thank you! sir :)

Answer (score 1):

You're reusing `rl` to do the unlock by overwriting `l_type` with `F_UNLCK`, and you're not resetting `l_type` in the loop. Both of your examples are locking only on the first loop iteration.